# curl отправка писем через GMail

Tags: c++, curl, email, windows-10

Новая напасть. Программа, которая автоматически слала письма месяца два назад через GMail с использованием

```
smtps://smtp.gmail.com:465
```

теперь не работает. Да, она запускалась давненько, но я зашел в аккаунт GMail - сторонние приложения разрешены.

Сейчас выдает

```
* Expire in 0 ms for 6 (transfer 0x14a9e90)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x14a9e90)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x14a9e90)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x14a9e90)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x14a9e90)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x14a9e90)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x14a9e90)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x14a9e90)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x14a9e90)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x14a9e90)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x14a9e90)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x14a9e90)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x14a9e90)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x14a9e90)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x14a9e90)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x14a9e90)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x14a9e90)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x14a9e90)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x14a9e90)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x14a9e90)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x14a9e90)
* Expire in 4 ms for 1 (transfer 0x14a9e90)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x14a9e90)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x14a9e90)
* Expire in 8 ms for 1 (transfer 0x14a9e90)
* Expire in 8 ms for 1 (transfer 0x14a9e90)
* Expire in 8 ms for 1 (transfer 0x14a9e90)
* Expire in 13 ms for 1 (transfer 0x14a9e90)
*   Trying 108.177.14.109...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x14a9e90)
* connect to 108.177.14.109 port 465 failed: Timed out
* Failed to connect to smtp.gmail.com port 465: Timed out
* Closing connection 0
```

Поменял порт на 587, имеем

```
* Expire in 4 ms for 1 (transfer 0x158a508)
* Expire in 4 ms for 1 (transfer 0x158a508)
* Expire in 4 ms for 1 (transfer 0x158a508)
* Expire in 8 ms for 1 (transfer 0x158a508)
* Expire in 9 ms for 1 (transfer 0x158a508)
* Expire in 9 ms for 1 (transfer 0x158a508)
* Expire in 16 ms for 1 (transfer 0x158a508)
* Expire in 50 ms for 1 (transfer 0x158a508)
* Expire in 50 ms for 1 (transfer 0x158a508)
* Expire in 32 ms for 1 (transfer 0x158a508)
* Expire in 50 ms for 1 (transfer 0x158a508)
* Expire in 50 ms for 1 (transfer 0x158a508)
* Expire in 64 ms for 1 (transfer 0x158a508)
* Expire in 50 ms for 1 (transfer 0x158a508)
* Expire in 50 ms for 1 (transfer 0x158a508)
* Expire in 50 ms for 1 (transfer 0x158a508)
*   Trying 108.177.14.108...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x158a508)
* Connected to smtp.gmail.com (108.177.14.108) port 587 (#0)
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with smtp.gmail.com port 587 (step 1/3)
* schannel: disabled server certificate revocation checks
* schannel: verifyhost setting prevents Schannel from comparing the supplied target name with the subject name
s in server certificates.
* schannel: sending initial handshake data: sending 176 bytes...
* schannel: sent initial handshake data: sent 176 bytes
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with smtp.gmail.com port 587 (step 2/3)
* schannel: failed to receive handshake, need more data
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with smtp.gmail.com port 587 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 365
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 365 length 4096
* schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_INVALID_TOKEN (0x80090308) - Предоставленный функции
токен неправилен
* Closing connection 0
```

Что ему не нравится? Что я делаю не так? Что-то изменилось на GMail? Пароли-логины не менялись.

Словом, в растерянности...

Comment: ну так говорит, что токен неверный. Дайте ему новый.

Comment: @KoVadim А как? Я ему раньше никаких токенов не давал, все просто так раборало.

Comment: Вы в `smtps://smtp.gmail.com:465` поменяли только порт? Попробуйте тогда заменить протокол на `smtp`.

Comment: @HarryfromKiev Тогда ругается `< 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first.`...

Comment: Опции типа `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USE_SSL, (long)CURLUSESSL_ALL);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);` установлены?

Comment: Спасибо! Оформите как ответ, чтоб принять...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы перешли не просто на другой порт, но и на иной протокол.

В соответствии с кодом на [сайте curl](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/smtp-tls.html), следует использовать url типа

```
smtp://mainserver.example.net:587
```

и установить некоторые опции:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USE_SSL, (long)CURLUSESSL_ALL);
```

и если у вас нет сертификата ()а судя по вопросу, его нет)

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
```